# Do Korea and Japan have their own national hashing standard?

Tags: hash, block-cipher, reference-request, standards

I know China has SM3 and SM4 commercial cryptographic hash and block cipher standards, and I know Japan has Camellia block cipher and Korea has SEED. Do Japan and Korea have an industry standard for hashing? Are they available online (either paid or free)?

Comment: [Korean LSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LSH_(hash_function)) not to be confused with the [Local Sensitive Hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing)

Comment: I think that [CRYPTREC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRYPTREC) is pretty much definitive when it comes to Japan: no candidate hash functions, only certain SHA-2 hashes allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Korea has its own standard for hash and block cipher, such as LSH (for hash) and ARIA (for block cipher). Source code can be found in [here](https://seed.kisa.or.kr/kisa/reference/EgovSource.do). I cannot find the English page, but google translator seems to work well. You can find information about standardization and other documents on the website, e.g. [here](https://seed.kisa.or.kr/kisa/algorithm/EgovLSHInfo.do).

The above-linked site KISA is itself authoritative and a public institute. If you want a much formal standard document, you could find them from [TTA](http://www.tta.or.kr/) or [KSA](https://ksa.or.kr/ksa_kr/index.do). The standard is as follows.

- LSH hash: KS X 3262 [KS Link](https://www.kssn.net/en/search/stddetail.do?itemNo=K001010120989), previously TTAK.KO-12.0276 (expired)
- LEA encryption: TTAK.KO-12.0223 [TTA Link](http://www.tta.or.kr/eng/new/standardization/eng_ttastddesc.jsp?stdno=TTAK.KO-12.0223) but the document is mostly in Korean. Source code is available [here](https://seed.kisa.or.kr/kisa/Board/20/detailView.do) but its manual is also in Korean.
- ARIA encryption: KS X 1213-1 [KS Link](https://www.kssn.net/en/search/stddetail.do?itemNo=K001010126229)

The documents on KS site are not free, and they are also written in Korean.

Comment: I'm fine with Korean text, and I suppose others who seek authoritative info would be fine with it, so please do link to official websites and sources.

Comment: @DannyNiu I added official sources.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding Japan, to my knowledge the JIS standards are just mapped to ISO standards, and I do not know of any main stream hash that is unique to Japan.  The JIS standard for hash functions (ハッシュ関数 is hash function if you want to just google around and translate) is JIS X 5057-2, and that is just basically a translation of ISO 10118-2.  I also know that the use of SHA-1 is outlined as the standard JIS hash function as of 2018, but I don't have my JIS documents handy.

Comment: I can sensibly tell from my limited knowledge of Japanese, that, "ハッシュ" is the transliteration for the word "hash", and "関数" looks not unlike the Chinese (my nativity) word "函数" meaning "function".

Comment: @DannyNiu Yeah.  I went to china and I could read (sorta) but not write.  It's was surreal.